# Cannot find option to uninstall a program

Tags: installation, uninstall, regedit

So I have this game "Rise of the Tomb Raider" installed on my machine.
I can't find it on the uninstall page in the control panel.

According to answers in other question, I also tried to uninstall it through the REGEDIT way but couldn't find the game over there too.

Also there is no uninstall executable present for the game.

Is there any way to uninstall the same?

Note : I have tried answer in the suggestion to this question but that did not work for me.

Comment: One avenue of approach I have tried is to install the app. That may present an option for Change and then Uninstall.  Or after the second install, you now may be able to uninstall.

Comment: Did you get this game legally from steam,  MS store or other

Comment: Legally from steam

Answer (score 1):

*Rise of the Tomb Raider* for Windows is distributed using the Microsoft Store and Steam on Windows.

The Store version entry would not be where you're looking. Simply right-click in Start menu and select Uninstall. Alternatively, you can also go to the *new* Settings app and do it from there.

The Steam version would show up where you're looking, but display names may be localized. They're not saved in the registry then. Either way, you can uninstall from inside the Steam client itself.

Comment: Well, yes. Questions about pirated software are banned. Also, the pirated version couldn’t possibly use an official install method, so you’re on your own either way.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can occur if the program you installed creates a registry key name that is longer than 60 characters in length. Add/Remove Programs only lists program names it locates up to the point it encounters this situation.

Please be caution to edit registry key since it's very important. For added protection, back up the registry before you modify it. Then, you can restore the registry if a problem occurs. For more information about how to back up and restore the registry, please kindly check [this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-back-up-and-restore-the-registry-in-windows-855140ad-e318-2a13-2829-d428a2ab0692).

To work around this problem, use one of the following methods:

**Method 1 Use the Uninstall Command Displayed in the Registry**

1. Use Registry Editor (Regedit.exe) to view the following registry key:
   **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall**
2. Double-click the UninstallString registry value, copy the contents of the Value Data box by selecting the contents and pressing CTRL+C, and then quit Registry Editor.
3. Click Start, click Run, press CTRL+V to paste the uninstall command, and then click OK.

**Method 2 Shorten the Registry Key Name**

1. Run Regedit.exe to view the following registry key:
   **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall**
2. Click the registry key for the program you installed, click Rename on the Edit menu, and then use a name with less than 60 characters. Note that if the DisplayName value is longer than 32 characters, it is not displayed. To rename it, double-click DisplayName and use a name up to 32 characters in length.

For more information, please refer to the following article:
[Program Is Not Listed in Add/Remove Programs After Installation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/program-is-not-listed-in-add-remove-programs-after-installation-0866db2a-f8d9-fb0f-16d2-850f5072e536)

Comment: I have mentioned in he question right, that the game program is not even there in REGEDIT and I went through all programs registry key but that program was nowhere to be found.